# error with urllib on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, urllib

I import urllib in my script with : `import urllib2 as urllib`

but when i push my app to heroku, I have this error :

```
   remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
    remote:        Collecting urllib (from -r /tmp/build_1d35698f2d5b9e170c92042828569c91/requirements.txt (line 3))
    remote:          Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement urllib (from -r /tmp/build_1d35698f2d5b9e170c92042828569c91/requirements.txt (line 3)) (from versions: )
    remote:        No matching distribution found for urllib (from -r /tmp/build_1d35698f2d5b9e170c92042828569c91/requirements.txt (line 3))
    remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
    remote:
    remote:  !     Push failed
```

what can I do ?
Thanks by advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`urllib2` is a built-in package in Python 2 (renamed to `urllib.request` and `urllib.error` in Python 3). Therefore it doesn't need to be installed and it should not be in your requirements.txt.

Remove `urllib` or `urllib2` from the requirements.txt file (hint: given from your error, remove `urllib` from the third line of requirements.txt) then your error should be gone.